# May Jews remove fake nails/eyelashes on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh, orach-chaim, borer-separating

According to halacha, is it permissible for Jews (particularly women) to remove fake eyelashes/nails from  their bodies on Shabbat? Would it be any problem of borer or handling mutzkeh? Or is it Muttar?

Comment: If they are attached with glue, why aren’t you concerned with koreah/tearing? If the glue residue remains and needs to be removed, there is additional issues to be addressed, although not as serious